# Unable to open "Lutris" on ubuntu[18.10] for gaming

Tags: wine, games, 18.10

I wanted to play windows games on Ubuntu. And I found that we can use **Lutris** along with `wine` for managing games. I installed the application as given in official webpage: [Lutris Download Page](https://lutris.net/downloads/)

But after installation, the program is not opening.
So what I can I do to open?
Any other suggestion on gaming on Ubuntu is also welcome.

Running through terminal gives the following result:

```
madhurachanna@madhurachanna-Inspiron-5559:~$ lutris
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lutris", line 29, in <module>
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, locale_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/locale.py", line 598, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lutris", line 31, in <module>
    sys.stderr.write("Unsupported locale %s. Try running with LC_ALL=C.\n" % locale_name)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: you can try to start it in a terminal and post, what it returns

Comment: I have updated the question, please check

Comment: You can also install `PlayOnLinux`, it have database for games and can use number of wine versions known to work fine with a game.

Comment: `locale.Error: unsupported locale setting` and `Try running with LC_ALL=C`

Answer (score 0):

This is because litrus is not able to find your system locale.

1. Goto Systems Settings ->  Language support
2. Set a system wide language
3. Restart system and relaunch litrus